# An algorithm for multiplying and marginalizing probability tables

Tags: javascript, probability, bayesian-networks

I am working implementing a specific Bayesian network library in Javascript.
Since I couldn't find any other library available online, I had to start from the scratch, including multiplying and marginalizing tables of probabilities (or potentials).

In marginalization, the column of the variable to be marginalized is taken out.
The common rows are then summed.
For example, *c* is to be marginalized from the table *phi(a,b,c)*.
The, the column relative to *c* is taken out and common rows *a* and *b* are summed, namely, *(0,0)* and *(1,1)* sum to 0.3 and 0.1, respectively.
[image]

In multiplication, we look in common variables (columns) for equal values.
We then multiply the matching rows.
For instance, the tables *phi(a,b)* and *phi(b,c)* are to be multiplied.
The common column is *b*.
Where *b* is 0 in both tables (with all possible combinations) we multiply the values.
[image: Multiplication of two potentials]

My first attempt was to implement the tables in a Map fashion, where each row is a *key* and the probabilities values are the *value*.
But it doesn't seem to be a good idea, because to implement multiplication we need to know the *label* of a variable. Therefore, I modified the code a little bit in order to get the labels from the function argument, but yet it didn't work because the rows are not directly related to the labels.
So, I left this code aside and now I'm looking for fresh new ideas.

Please, someone has any thought on how these examples could be achieved?

Comment: This won't be difficult if you can explain exactly how the calculations work, they're not intuitive at a quick look.

Comment: "*Therefore, I modified the code…*". What code? Is this purely a mapping exercise, or is there an algorithm for calculating the marginalisation?

Comment: I just modified the description, @Nit, to add more details on multiplication and marginalization operations. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, @RobG. It's my personal code, which I didn't show it here, since I think that my approach didn't work fine. I have extended the description for marginalization and multiplication, and I'm looking for a algorithm to solve those examples.

Comment: I think I get it. I the OP you have *(1,1)* sums to *0.1*, should that be *0.2*?

Comment: @RobG, there is not summing in *(1,1)*. Indeed, in the marginalized table, namely *phi(a,b)*, the row *(1,0)* is 0.1, since *(1,0)* has no matching row after column *c* is taken out. Sorry the poor description. I'm trying to improve it, while the feedbacks come in.

Comment: Yes, *(1,1)* has two matching rows, both with a value of *0.1* so *0.1 + 0.1 = 0.2*?

Comment: Are there only ever three columns, or can there be any number? Can marginalisation be to a single value (e.g. {a})?

Comment: Thanks, @RobG. Yes, you're right, but those matching *(1,1)* they sum to 0.2 (it's the third row in the marginalized table).
Yes, there can be more than three column and it doesn't make sense to marginalize a single value, so I think it's an easy exception to be treated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to do the job up to marginalise. It creates a table with rows that have members and a value. Each row in a table must have the same number of members.

It doesn't implement multiplication yet (real work has to be done sometime…). Note that in ECMAScript, `0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004` so you'll need to implement some kind of rounding to fix that and maintain accuracy.

```
/**
 * A table has rows, all rows within a table have the same number of members
 * Each row as 1 to n members plus a value
 * e.g. a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, value = 0.1
 *      a = 0, b = 0, c = 1, value = 0.2
 *      a = 1, b = 0, c = 0, value = 0.1
 *      a = 1, b = 1, c = 0, value = 0.1
 *      a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, value = 0.1
 *
 * Marginalisation addition takes the values of matching values and sums them,
 * 
 * e.g. 
 *      marginalisation of {a, b} where a=0 and b=0:
 *      matching rows are 0 and 1, so add 0.1 + 0.2 => 0.3
 *
 *      marginalisation of {a, b} where a=1 and b=1:
 *      matching rows are 3 and 4, so add 0.1 + 0.1 => 0.2
 *
 * @param {number} numberOfValues - number of values in each row. So for 3 members
 *                                  plus value then numberOfValues is 4
 */
function BayTable (numberOfValues) {

  // Array containing rows of values
  this.rows = [];

  // Number of values in a row, so for [a, b, c, value] memberCount is 4
  this.memberCount = numberOfValues;
}

/**
 * @param {number} memberValue[, memberValue, ...], rowValue
 *
 * e.g. addRow(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
 */
BayTable.prototype.addRow = function() {

  if (arguments.length != this.memberCount) return; // or throw error

  var row = [];

  for (var i=0, iLen=arguments.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    row.push(arguments[i]);
  }
  this.rows.push(row);
}

/**
 * marginalise finds matching rows and adds their values,
 * so marginalise(0,0) finds rows where a=0 and b=0 ignoring
 * any other member in the row and
 * sums the value for the rows
 */
BayTable.prototype.marginalise = function() {

  // Guard agains too many arguments
  if (arguments.length > this.memberCount - 2) return; // or throw error

  var total = 0;
  var row, match;

  // For each row
  for (var i=0, iLen=this.rows.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    row = this.rows[i];
    match = true

    // Check values against arguments until a missmatch
    for (var j=0, jLen=arguments.length; j<jLen && match; j++) {
      match = row[j] === arguments[j];
    }

    // If no missmatch, add row value
    if (match) total += row[row.length - 1];
  }
  return total;
}

var x = new BayTable(4);
x.addRow(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
x.addRow(0, 0, 1, 0.2);
x.addRow(1, 0, 0, 0.1);
x.addRow(1, 1, 0, 0.1);
x.addRow(1, 1, 1, 0.1);

console.log(x.marginalise(0, 0)); // 0.30000000000000004
console.log(x.marginalise(1, 0)); // 0.1
console.log(x.marginalise(1, 1)); // 0.2
```

Here's the object version, it uses a couple of ES5 methods:

```
/**
 * A table has rows, all rows within a table have the same number of members
 * Each row as 1 to n members plus a value
 * e.g. a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, value = 0.1
 *      a = 0, b = 0, c = 1, value = 0.2
 *      a = 1, b = 0, c = 0, value = 0.1
 *      a = 1, b = 1, c = 0, value = 0.1
 *      a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, value = 0.1
 *
 * Marginalisation addition takes the values of matching values and sums them,
 * 
 * e.g. 
 *      marginalisation of {a, b} where a=0 and b=0:
 *      matching rows are 0 and 1, so add 0.1 + 0.2 => 0.3
 *
 *      marginalisation of {a, b} where a=1 and b=1:
 *      matching rows are 3 and 4, so add 0.1 + 0.1 => 0.2
 *
 * @param {number} numberOfValues - number of values in each row. So for 3 members plus value
 *                                  then numberOfValues is 4
 */
function BayTable (numberOfValues) {

  // Array containing rows of values
  this.rows = [];

  // Number of values in a row, so for [a, b, c, value] memberCount is 4
  this.memberCount = numberOfValues;
}

/**
 * @param {Object} row - {label:value[, label:value, ...], 'value':value}
 *
 * e.g. addRow({a:0, b:0, c:0, value:0.1})
 */
BayTable.prototype.addRow = function(row) {
  this.rows.push(row);
}

/**
 * marginalise finds matching rows and adds their values,
 * so marginalise({a:0, b:0}) finds rows where a=0 and b=0 ignoring
 * any other member in the row and sums the values of matched rows
 */
BayTable.prototype.marginalise = function(obj) {

  var keys = Object.keys(obj);

  // For each row
  return this.rows.reduce(function(total, row) {

    // If all key/values match, accumlate value
    if (keys.every(function(key){return obj[key] === row[key]}))
      total += row.value;
    return total;
  }, 0);

/*
  // Less obscure version, same number of lines of code
  var total = 0;
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);

  // For each row
  this.rows.forEach(function(row) {

    // If key/values match, add row value to total
    if (keys.every(function(key){return obj[key] === row[key]}))
      total += row.value;
  });
  return total;
*/
}


var x = new BayTable(4);

x.addRow({a:0, b:0, c:0, value:0.1});
x.addRow({a:0, b:0, c:1, value:0.2});
x.addRow({a:1, b:0, c:0, value:0.1});
x.addRow({a:1, b:1, c:0, value:0.1});
x.addRow({a:1, b:1, c:1, value:0.1});

console.log(x.marginalise({a:0, b:0})); // 0.30000000000000004
console.log(x.marginalise({a:1, b:0})); // 0.1
console.log(x.marginalise({a:1, b:1})); // 0.2
console.log(x.marginalise({a:1, c:1})); // 0.1
console.log(x.marginalise({b:0, c:0})); // 0.2
```

Comment: That did the work for marginalizing, @RobG! I think that your greatest point was how you represented the table (as a simple array with the variable's domain *and* the values). I was using a Map, from the variable's domain to the value. I think your idea is better, since it's simpler. I'll try it out in my code. Thank you so much!

Comment: I realise now that it might be better to use objects rather than arrays, in the above it's impossible to marginalise *{a, c}* as members are represented by position not name. It's not a big change.

Comment: Good point. But yet you gave me insightful idea on how to deal with this table now. Thank you anyway.

Comment: That's it. The version with object is more consistent. Thanks, @RobG.